# How can i make this autocmd BufEnter command work?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, autocmd, statusline

i am setting the default vim-statusline, and i made this line on my colorscheme:

`hi MyStatusLineDevIcon ctermfg=7 ctermbg=0 cterm=NONE`

So i can color the devicons on my `statusline.vim` config

I call them using this function:

```
function! ShowDevIcons()
  return WebDevIconsGetFileTypeSymbol()
 endfunction
```

And set it on the statusline using this:

`set statusline+=%#MyStatuslineDevIcon#\`

Now, the settings are all working fine, the ctermfg value i put on my colorscheme changes the icons alright.

But i want to make a function to change the devicon based on the filetype, like this:

```
function! SetFiletype()
  let l:filetype = &filetype

  if l:filetype == "vim"
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * hi MyStatuslineDevIcon ctermbg=8 cterm=bold ctermfg=3
  endif
endfunction
```

But i can't make it work. It returns no errors but it doesn't change the color. If i enter the `hi MyStatuslineDevIcon ctermbg=8 cterm=bold ctermfg=3` command manually, it does the job, but the function is not working. Any help, please?

Comment: Dont use autocmd! without an augroup! (The first bang is part of the command; the second is for emphasis.)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the approach you described.

First, you are calling `autocmd!` outside of an `augroup`. This is really bad, since it's actually erasing *all* auto-commands!

Second, the logic in `SetFiletype()` looks odd, since it's first checking whether the file type is `"vim"` and then creating an auto-command to set the highlight group when entering a buffer (any buffer.)

If what you wanted to accomplish is to change the highlight group every time you enter a buffer with a specific filetype, it would make more sense to invert this approach, and have a fixed `autocmd` to call a function when you enter a buffer, and then in that function check for the `&filetype` and act appropriately. (You might also want to reset back to the original highlight group if you're entering a buffer of a different file type.)

For example:

```
function! SetMyStatusLineDevIconHighlight()
  if &filetype ==# 'vim'
    hi MyStatusLineDevIcon ctermbg=8 cterm=bold ctermfg=3
  else
    hi MyStatusLineDevIcon ctermfg=7 ctermbg=0 cterm=NONE
  endif
endfunction

augroup MyStatusLineDevIconGroup
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * call SetMyStatusLineDevIconHighlight()
augroup END
```

This will work... But it will probably *not* do what you want. You see, highlight groups are actually global in Vim and Vim will use the same one for every window you have. So if you have split windows and in one of them you're editing a file of type `"vim"`, but in the other you're editing a file of a different type, Vim will always switch the status line of *all* windows to the highlight of the window you're currently in. So when you switch from a `"vim"` window to a non-`"vim"` window or vice-versa, Vim will switch them all.

There are ways to set the `'statusline'` so that it takes the status of the current window (such as the file type of the buffer being edited there) in consideration, such as:

- Using `:setlocal` to set a local `'statusline'` setting for that specific window. You could set that in an `autocmd` for the `WinEnter` event, or even perhaps on one for a `FileType` event, then use a specific highlight for the filetype.
- Having `'statusline'` call a function to dynamically define what to use in the status line, then have that function look at the `g:statusline_winid` variable which is set by Vim during the call to that function and query the `&filetype` for the buffer being edited in that window. (That requires quite a few function calls in Vim to do right. Also, the `g:statusline_winid` is a fairly addition around the Vim 8.1 timeline, so it might not be available in older versions of Vim, if you care about compatibility.)

There are many more caveats. For instance, the normal setup is for Vim to use different color highlights when a window is in focus (is the one where the cursor is) or not, highlight groups [`StatusLine`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#hl-StatusLine) and [`StatusLineNC`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#hl-StatusLineNC) are used for this purpose. Then there are 9 additional groups [`User1` through `User9`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#hl-User1) which can be accessed through `%1*` through `%9*` settings in the `'statusline'` value. Furthermore, highlight settings for these `UserN` groups also apply on top of `StatusLineNC`, though only the difference with `StatusLine` is what applies there.

In short, `'statusline'` in Vim is quite complex and it's quite challenging to really get it right. But hopefully this answer will have addressed your question on `BufEnter` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `echom 'filetype '.&filetype` in `vimrc` and it's empty.

You might need to use `autocmd FileType` instead which is triggered when the `filetype` option is set. (`h FileType`)

You can try something like this to run commands only for `vim` type files

```
autocmd FileType vim hi MyStatuslineDevIcon ctermbg=8 cterm=bold ctermfg=3
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This seems more like an idea than a full solution; if you have time to dig deeper, feel free to [edit] to expand! FWIW, in my vimrc (`~/.vim/vimrc`), the filetype is correctly set…

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited my answer to be more like a solution.